# Adding Points to Polygon from an Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-maps

I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception when I try to add points to a Google Maps polygon from an array.

```
if(inPolygon.check(list[i].vertices, list[i].latCoords, list[i].longCoords, latitude, longitude) != true) {

    PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
                for(int n = 0; n <= list[i].vertices; n++){
                    rectOptions.add(new LatLng(list[i].latCoords[n], list[i].longCoords[n]));
                }
}
```

I have an array of objects (list), and each object has two arrays: one for latitude coordinates (latCoords), and one for longitude coordinates (longCoords). I'd like to create a polygon from coordinates of both arrays by iterating through them as you see with the for loop.

But I keep getting a null pointer exception when I try to do this, and I'm not sure why. I'd appreciate any help or suggestions for this issue, as I'm just a beginner in Maps/Android development.

Comment: *Where* is the exception happening, and are you sure that `list` is non-null and only contains non-null references?

Comment: LogCat is pointing to the line that adds the points to the polygon (116). I believe list is non-null as it contains two objects.

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* this is the problem:

```
for(int n = 0; n <= list[i].vertices; n++)
```

You're using `n` here:

```
list[i].latCoords[n]
```

(and same with `longCoords`) - and so when `n` is *equal* to `list[i].vertices`, that may be a null reference.

I suspect you want your loop check to be strictly less than (which is much more common):

```
for (int n = 0; n < list[i].vertices; n++)
```

Comment: Hmm.. When I do this I get a different error. "IndexOutofBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0".

Comment: @RowanK.: Well I suspect you get that at a different place, which is progress. So next you need to look at where *that's* happening, and address it.

Comment: It says I'm getting that error at line 121, which is the line where I create the polygon     Polygon polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);

Comment: @RowanK.: Well you haven't even shown us that code... you should try to diagnose it yourself, and if you can't work out what's wrong ask a *new* question with all the relevant code.